# Tkinter Label If-Else Condition

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

Trying to make a simple if-else condition like below:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
x = 10

    if x = 10:
        Label(root, text="equal to 10")
    else:
        Label(root, text="not equal to 10")

pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However,i take an error message:

```
  File "deneme1.py", line 5
    if x = 10:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Not the cause of your error, but you mean `x == 10`. One = is assignment. And you're probably mixing tabs and spaces. Be consistent with you indentation

Comment: Have you searched this site or the internet, or just python documentation for `IndentationError`?

Comment: Indention is one of the first basic concepts learned in python and probably many other languages. You may need to get through several entry level tutorials before you start asking questions here on stack overflow as many if not all of the basic questions like this one has already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` shouldn't be indented. Indentation means that somethings "inside" the scope of whatever came before it. Your `if` can't be inside the scope of an assignment; that doesn't make sense.

Just give your `if` the same indentation as the first assignment.

Also note that to compare things, you use `==`. `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `if` at the same indent level as your `x`:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
x = 10

if x == 10:
    Label(root, text="equal to 10")
else:
    Label(root, text="not equal to 10")

pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In general, you will only indent to the next level after a colon

```
def for_instance():
    print('in a function')

    try:
        or_possibly
    except AttributeError:
        print('in a try/except block at both the try and except')
```